# D3.js - How to use inline JSON as dataset for D3 charts, instead of csv/tsv/json file

Tags: d3.js

I'm implementing D3.js charts in my application, I don't want to use file as dataset, I just want to use inline JSON as dataset (JSON would be generated dynamically in application).

I have done implementation for [Reusable Responsive Multiline Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/asielen/44ffca2877d0132572cb) using following code.

```
var data1 = [ { "My JSON data here" } ];

d3.json('', function (error, data) {

    data1.forEach(function (d) {
        d.year = +d.year;
        d.variableA = +d.variableA;
        d.variableB = +d.variableB;
        d.variableC = +d.variableC;
        d.Temp = +d.Temp;
    });

    var chart = makeLineChart(data1, 'year', {
        'Device 1': { column: 'variableA' },
        'Device 2': { column: 'variableB' },
        'Device 3': { column: 'variableC' },
        'Device 4': { column: 'variableD' }
    }, { xAxis: 'Years', yAxis: 'Temperature' });
    chart.bind("#chart-line1");
    chart.render();
});
```

Here I'm calling d3.json() but **file name is blank** and also there is **no use of data** in code. Instead of 'data' I'm using 'data1'.
**It works perfect ...**

Now I want to achieve the same for [Grouped Bar Chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051), but this chart data binding method is different than "Reusable Responsive Multiline Chart".
Following is the code to parse data for "Grouped Bar Chart".

```
d3.csv("\\data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var keys = data.columns.slice(1); 

  // Rest of code to bind parsed data to chart   
});
```

Complete code at [Grouped Bar Chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051)

So how I can replace *data.csv* with inline JSON here.

Comment: Try to add `d = [ { "My JSON data here" } ];` on the second line, after `d3.csv()` and before the `for`

Comment: @TheBiro You mean to say, replacing "\\data.csv" with 'd = [ { "My JSON data here" } ];' will work? I'm not getting clearly where to add d = [ { "My JSON data here" } ];.

Comment: just remove the call to `d3.json` and use your generated data

Comment: No, my idea was to overwrite the data `d` with your json inside `d3.csv`.

Comment: @TheBiro it's not working, I just tired as follow :  `d3.csv("", function(d = [ { "State": "CA", "Under 5 Years": 2704659, "5 to 13 Years": 4499890, "14 to 17 Years": 2159981, "18 to 24 Years": 3853788, "25 to 44 Years": 10604510, "45 to 64 Years": 8819342, "65 Years and Over": 4114496 }, { "State": "TX", "Under 5 Years": 2027307, "5 to 13 Years": 3277946, "14 to 17 Years": 1420518, "18 to 24 Years": 2454721, "25 to 44 Years": 7017731, "45 to 64 Years": 5656528, "65 Years and Over": 2472223 } ], i, columns) {` it shows following Error: <text> attribute y: Expected length, "NaN". in D3.js file.

Comment: @thedude the first one is working example `d3.json` ... I want your help for second example `d3.csv`. please read question carefully, you will understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods `d3.json` and `d3.csv` are AJAX calls meant to fetch data **from the server**.  If you have in-line JSON, you do not need these calls.  The fact that your first example works like that is just a side-effect.  Your `d3.json` call *fails* but the call-back function is still executed.  It's just un-necessary and should be written as:

```
var data1 = [ { "My JSON data here" } ];

data1.forEach(function (d) {
    d.year = +d.year;
    d.variableA = +d.variableA;
    d.variableB = +d.variableB;
    d.variableC = +d.variableC;
    d.Temp = +d.Temp;
});

var chart = makeLineChart(data1, 'year', {
    'Device 1': { column: 'variableA' },
    'Device 2': { column: 'variableB' },
    'Device 3': { column: 'variableC' },
    'Device 4': { column: 'variableD' }
}, { xAxis: 'Years', yAxis: 'Temperature' });
chart.bind("#chart-line1");
chart.render();
```

On your second chart again the call to `d3.csv` is not necessary.  There is however some processing that happens from the CSV format to JSON.  You'll need to replicate that in creating your JSON and for the rest of the chart to work you'll need something like:

```
...

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var data = [{"State":"CA","Under 5 Years":2704659,"5 to 13 Years":4499890,"14 to 17 Years":2159981,"18 to 24 Years":3853788,"25 to 44 Years":10604510,"45 to 64 Years":8819342,"65 Years and Over":4114496},{"State":"TX","Under 5 Years":2027307,"5 to 13 Years":3277946,"14 to 17 Years":1420518,"18 to 24 Years":2454721,"25 to 44 Years":7017731,"45 to 64 Years":5656528,"65 Years and Over":2472223}];

var keys = ["Under 5 Years", "5 to 13 Years", "14 to 17 Years", "18 to 24 Years", "25 to 44 Years", "45 to 64 Years", "65 Years and Over"]

x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);

...
```

Here's that code running **without** the call to `d3.csv`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

.axis .domain {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
    .padding(0.05);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var data = [{"State":"CA","Under 5 Years":2704659,"5 to 13 Years":4499890,"14 to 17 Years":2159981,"18 to 24 Years":3853788,"25 to 44 Years":10604510,"45 to 64 Years":8819342,"65 Years and Over":4114496},{"State":"TX","Under 5 Years":2027307,"5 to 13 Years":3277946,"14 to 17 Years":1420518,"18 to 24 Years":2454721,"25 to 44 Years":7017731,"45 to 64 Years":5656528,"65 Years and Over":2472223},{"State":"NY","Under 5 Years":1208495,"5 to 13 Years":2141490,"14 to 17 Years":1058031,"18 to 24 Years":1999120,"25 to 44 Years":5355235,"45 to 64 Years":5120254,"65 Years and Over":2607672},{"State":"FL","Under 5 Years":1140516,"5 to 13 Years":1938695,"14 to 17 Years":925060,"18 to 24 Years":1607297,"25 to 44 Years":4782119,"45 to 64 Years":4746856,"65 Years and Over":3187797},{"State":"IL","Under 5 Years":894368,"5 to 13 Years":1558919,"14 to 17 Years":725973,"18 to 24 Years":1311479,"25 to 44 Years":3596343,"45 to 64 Years":3239173,"65 Years and Over":1575308},{"State":"PA","Under 5 Years":737462,"5 to 13 Years":1345341,"14 to 17 Years":679201,"18 to 24 Years":1203944,"25 to 44 Years":3157759,"45 to 64 Years":3414001,"65 Years and Over":1910571}];

var keys = ["Under 5 Years", "5 to 13 Years", "14 to 17 Years", "18 to 24 Years", "25 to 44 Years", "45 to 64 Years", "65 Years and Over"];

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
  x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(keys, function(key) { return d[key]; }); })]).nice();

  g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); });

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", 2)
      .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .text("Population");

  var legend = g.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(keys.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 19)
      .attr("width", 19)
      .attr("height", 19)
      .attr("fill", z);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

</script>
```